# ioredis in nodejs does nothing when 'get' from AWS ElastiCache Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, amazon-ecs, amazon-elasticache, ioredis

I am running the following code in a nodejs container hosted on ECS. This runs great locally using redis. In AWS, it appears to connect (if I use an invalid address it errors on connection so I'm assuming it's connected). When I run `redis.get(` nothing happens. I've enabled debugging for ioredis and I get 1 message when I attempt the get:

```
2020-04-17T22:56:10.701Z ioredis:redis status[replica.virtual-happy-hour-redis.fnt3zc.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379]: [empty] -> connecting
2020-04-17T22:56:11.042Z ioredis:redis status[10.200.0.37:6379]: connecting -> connect
2020-04-17T22:56:11.045Z ioredis:redis write command[10.200.0.37:6379]: 0 -> info([])
2020-04-17T23:02:02.627Z ioredis:redis queue command[10.200.0.37:6379]: 0 -> get([ 'friday' ])
# suspense is killing me....
```

Here's the code

```
var Redis = require('ioredis'),

console.log('cache connecting to', CONFIG.CACHE_URL);
var redis = new Redis(CONFIG.CACHE_URL);
console.log('cache connected');

const getRoom = (roomName, callback) => {
  let room;
  console.log('getRoom', roomName); // this logs as expected, nothing after this does
  try {
    redis.get(roomName, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('get cache error', err);
      } else {
        if (result) {
          console.log('cache result', result);
          room = JSON.parse(result);
        } else {
          console.log('no cache', roomName);
          room = defaultRoom(roomName);
          redis.set(roomName, JSON.stringify(room));
        }
      }
      if (callback) callback(room);
      console.log('getRoom done');
    });
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log('getRoom error', ex.toString());
  }
};
```

I've confirmed security groups, ElastiCache is in the same VPC as my ECS container. What can I do to troubleshoot this?

**UPDATE**
I swapped out `ioredis` with `redis` and it still happens, nada...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it! I wasn't aware I (newb to AWS) configured ElastiCache for Encryption in Transit. Once I set the auth token and used that with `ioredis` it works! I'm back in business!

Comment: I am in similar issue. Pls can you show what exactly u did ?

Comment: likewise whats the auth token and where is it from

Comment: @David Lozzi can you please add more details for your answer? Facing issue with npm redis and ioredis. For redis version 3.1.2 its working fine but i want to get it work with latest version.

Comment: I solved it by enabling tls encription on ioredis connection:
const redis = new Redis({
    host: REDIS_HOST,
    port: REDIS_PORT,
    tls: {}, // Enable TLS encryption
    db: 0
  });